# Why can irb not find this gem?

Tags: ruby

I am a beginner following this tutorial:
https://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

I named my gem Ciao instead of Hola.

When I get to the part of the tutorial for installing the gem locally I get an error:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'ciao'   
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /Users/stage/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
    3: from (irb):1
    2: from /Users/stage/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    1: from /Users/stage/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
LoadError (cannot load such file -- ciao)
```

- Why do the ruby version numbers not match?
- Why is line 1 and 2 repeated? ✔️ answered by @tadman
- Why can irb not find this poor little gem?

Thank you.

--- FOLLOWUP ---

```
stages-MacBook:ciao stage$ gem build ciao.gemspec
WARNING:  no homepage specified
WARNING:  See http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/ for help
Successfully built RubyGem
Name: ciao
Version: 0.0.0
File: ciao-0.0.0.gem

irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> false
```

Comment: Is your gem actually installed? Does `require 'rubygems'` prior to that line help?

Comment: Line 1 and 2 are repeated because that's a stack trace and it just lists where in the code the trouble occurs. It could be a recursive call, as in it calls itself.

Comment: Did you run `gem build ciao.gemspec` and `gem install ciao-0.0.0.gem`?

Comment: @kimmo-lehto thank you for your response.

Comment: @tadman thank you for your response.